# How to pass globals from main thread to workers

Tags: node.js, multithreading, global

I am starting to use nodejs 12 and trying to pass from main thread that open workers I need to pass some globals this run with codeceptjs automation,
The issue that before I have one main thread and now I want to handle workers also but don't know how the globals will be available on workers.
My code for single is

```
  global.host =getHost();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use module.exports

example like
module.exports.host = getHost();

followed by:

const n = require('./path of file you exported');

n.host;